# C# Entity Framework : how do I filter 5 behavior columns that hold a specific behavior letter?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a C# Winforms app that is using Entity Framework. I have buttons on the form that is supposed to query individual behavior types from the database. The table has 5 columns that can hold a different behavior letter so I need to search each column in each record if it contains that letter.

Here is my code:

```
    public static List<Behaviors_Collection> BxButtonPush(string BX, string client)
    {
        DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse("06-01-2021");

        using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
        {
            List<Behaviors_Collection> GetBXData = context.Behaviors_Collection.Where(
                x => x.BX1 == BX 
                || x.BX2 == BX || x.BX3 == BX || x.BX4 == BX 
                || x.BX5 == BX && x.Client == client 
                && x.Date >= startdate).ToList();

            return GetBXData;
        }
    }
```

I'm new to coding in C# so I'm not entirely sure how to really do it. My attempt returns 368 records that don't match any of the parameters.

How can I better write this so it returns the correct data. Any suggestions would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: I removed the sql server tag. While it may be the DBMS you are using, this question is entirely about c# and the DBMS is irrelevant to the question in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly, so I don't know if this could be causing the issue - but operator precedence is a thing. `a || b && c` is the same `a || (b && c)`. I'm guessing you would need to wrap a paranthesis around your ORs. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)

Comment: You also might want to consider normalising your database so, rather than having five or more columns, have a separate linked table/entity with BX values and a column number - the design is then extenable.

Comment: @Jákup - This worked for me, thank you so much for the help, and for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of operator precedence. `a || b && c` is the same as `a || (b && c)`. You need to wrap a paranthesis around your ORs. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)

```
public static List<Behaviors_Collection> BxButtonPush(string BX, string client)
{
    DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse("06-01-2021");

    using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
    {
        List<Behaviors_Collection> GetBXData = context.Behaviors_Collection.Where(x =>
            (x.BX1 == BX || x.BX2 == BX || x.BX3 == BX || x.BX4 == BX 
            || x.BX5 == BX) &&
            x.Client == client && x.Date >= startdate).ToList();

        return GetBXData;
    }
}
```